# How do I check the first index of an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays

Say I have a value...

`x = 5`

and a numpy array of arrays which looks something like...

`arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]`

how would I check the first index of each array (ie. 1, 3, 5) to see if they = x?

Comment: `arr[:,0]==5` won't do?

Comment: Well, first of all, what have you tried?

Comment: Can you write code that gives you the `[1, 3, 5]` values? Can you write code that takes a 1-dimensional array and compares its values to `x`? If you put those things together, does that solve the problem? If not, did you try working through a Numpy tutorial in order to learn how to do these fundamental things? (Being able to do things like this with simple code is a major part of the reason to use Numpy in the first place.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find `any()` function useful in this case. It takes a list as an argument, and returns **True** if any of their arguments evaluate to **True** (and **False** otherwise).
Here's how you do

```
if any([i[0] == x for i in arr]):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map a lambda function to your array:

```
result = list(map(lambda y: y[0] == x, arr))
```

This returns

```
[False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for i in arr:
    if i[0]==x:
      print('found it')
```

Answer (score 0):

From my first comment, the most straightforward answer would be slicing:

```
arr[:,0]==x
```

Which would give you

```
array([False, False, True])
```